# a link is not working when span is generated in it via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamically-generated

Hi I am building a site on sharepoint and I need to ad a span on first word in a tag to style it properly. check this link please: https://anegis-public.sharepoint.com/

I am doing this by adding this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.menu-item-text').each(function(){
     var me = $(this);
     me.html(me.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

But as you can seen on above link the click on span is not working. So clicking on second word works but first word with span doesnt work. the script is working here fine http://jsfiddle.net/Hymma/6/

I can do any change in html all i have to do with js or css.

Comment: I am using Opera 15 (if that is of any use) and clicking on the `span` does work.

Comment: I've tested in Safari and Firefox and the fiddle works fine, no matter where I click. The source looks good, too.

Comment: The fiddle works fine, but the site doesn't. In opera and firefox under linux.
Edit: Maybe you have some javascript that returns false or prevents default on click on this element?

Comment: @paulina It most likely is because as you mentioned, the problem is happening for me also when I access the site.

Comment: The current content generated by the site is `<span class="menu-item-text"><span class="black">Who </span>we are</span>` but if I change it (using console) to `<span class="menu-item-text"><span class="menu-item-text black">Who </span>we are</span>`. So check if there is some event associated with `.menu-item-text`'s click.

Answer (score 0):

thanks harry,  insertusernamehere and pulina, the problem was with .menu-item-text class, as i can not edit html or other js files so I added this class to generated span as mentioned by harry. and now its working fine. lolzzzz another strange stuff from microsoft.